# Extract (Raw or Encoded) Video Frames from any GPU Memory directly for Current Program?

Tags: c++, gpu, nvidia, video-processing, nvenc

I have been working on `Camera Video Frame Capturing` for the past year. I am trying to make a video streaming plugin using `webrtc` and its associated technologies. I know that there are some certain plugins already in the market to stream video i.e. `PixelStreaming`.

Recently, I came up with new research which is required in order to perform the following;

> As the `latency` is the key factor in order to develop more reliable
> streaming plugins. So, I was trying my best to optimize every process
> running during *Camera Video Frame Capturing*. I am also trying to reduce the number
> of extra hops during this procedure.

---

This current system which I have developed is working `100` percent **fine without any crash** as you can see here;

[image]

My concerning point here is that Is there any possibility that I can extract camera video frames either `RAW` or `Encoded` from GPU directly?

As I want to run `Camera` using GPU i.e. `Nvidia GPU (GTX GEFORCE)` and I can get some details using a Python module for getting the GPU status from NVIDIA GPUs using Nvidia-SMI programmatically in Python. But It does not give me any access to get, fetch or extract video frames of that Camera running on GPU.

---

**Simple Example:**

As an example, let's take an example of a simple camera and its frames being processed by `GPU` instead of `CPU` such as;

[image]

I have visited this pretty cool answer:

- [Lowest overhead camera to CPU to GPU approach on android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37513328/10413749)

> As far as the `Nvidia Encoder` is concerned, I have also worked with
> this pretty cool encoder and successfully managed to encode raw video
> frames using `NvEnc`. I am also aware of its C/C++ implementation
> directly.

Let's take another very simple example. I have tried to allocate memory in GPU using `cudaMalloc` CUDA C++ Programming. I am also able to copy allocated GPU memory into Host Program using `cudaMemcpy` such as;

```
int main()
{
    const unsigned int N = 1048576;
    const unsigned int bytes = N * sizeof(int);
    int *h_a = (int*)malloc(bytes);
    int *d_a;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&d_a, bytes);

    memset(h_a, 0, bytes);
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(h_a, d_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any `plugin`, `module`, `library`, or some piece of advice someone can give me about extracting frames directly from GPU without taking frames from Camera every time for the **current running process/program**.?